# Hair is always sideways

Tags: hair

My hair particle system always spawns sideways like in the picture.

What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is normal.  Some people create their source object/group lying down so that it's upright when Blender uses it, so you could simply rotate your source object.

However, you can fix it in the Particle System settings.
Select the particle system tab and find the Rotation section.
There is a setting "Initial Orientation", which is probably set to "None" or "Velocity/Hair".
Try changing this to "Global Z".  (depending on the orientation of your original object, you might need to use a different one).

Comment: For information, I think the documentation is incorrect here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/rotation.html#initial-rotation as it should be "Sets the initial rotation of the particle by aligning the **Y** axis in the direction of"

Comment: I have a feeling that in earlier versions of Blender, it was aligned with Y, but was later changed to X, but don't quote me on that!  It may be that this change was overlooked in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem last night on Blender 3.2.1. No matter what I did, I couldn't get the hair pointing up, yet it would work in a brand new file.

My problem was that I'd introduced the hair half way through a project at some random point on the timeline and I had wind in my scene. The actual frame I was playing with just so happened to be in a wind "blow", so no matter which settings I used, even the ones that were correct, it was being "blown" to the side without me realising.

I went back to frame 0 and it worked as expected. Under field weights, I turned wind down to 0 so it wouldn't be affected at any point in the animation, which suited my scenario anyway (grass shadow catcher being overlaid on video footage).

Hope that helps someone.